# The use of the terms "spectral" and "spectrum"

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

The first use of the word spectrum I know in mathematics is with respect to linear operators (or perhaps more simply matrices). In particular, we define the spectrum of a linear operator $T$ to be:

$$
\sigma(T) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}: T - \lambda I \text{ is not invertible}\}
$$

However, I have also heard the term "spectral" used in the subject of Fourier Analysis/signal processing. Could anyone explain to me what this means, and if it is related to the spectrum of linear algebra/operator theory?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3660198/81360) for one perspective

Comment: In the context of Fourier series, the "spectrum" of a function (i.e. the Fourier series coefficients) is also the "spectrum" of the convolution operator associated with  that function

Comment: @BenGrossmann Interesting, thanks for that relationship. I have also heard Fourier series as a spectral theorem between Hilbert Spaces, applied to the eigenvalues of the Laplacian (on a bounded domain). I assume this generalizes to the Fourier transform in some way? I am not sure as to what the spectrum of the Laplacian is on the full space, $\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: It is related to the spectrum of the atom. The values of $\lambda$ for which $(A-\lambda I)$ is not invertible was being studied for compact operators by Hilbert, and the set of singular values $\lambda$ reminded Hilbert of atomic spectral lines, and that's how Hilbert came to name the set "spectrum." And, of course, we now know that the spectral lines correspond to the spectrum of operators in Physics. So, quite happily, the Mathematician's spectrum and the Physicists spectrum correspond.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts that makes sense. What is the link between atomic spectra and Fourier Analysis? Or maybe put differently - why is the analysis of a signal in the frequency domain described with the adjective "spectral"?

Comment: The connection is an evolution system $\frac{dx}{dt} = Hx(t)$, and the spectrum of the  controlling operator.